# How to Multiply Particles Dynamic Weight Paint?

Tags: particles, dynamic-paint

When I use Dynamic Paint to paint the particle weight onto the Canvas (lets say with the weight value of 0.1), other particles that paint on top of the previous are not accumulative.

[image]

Like when ten particles with the weight of 0.1 (light blue) hit the same place to become 1.0 (red). Is it possible for the weight to accumulate like that?

Thank you.

[image]

---

Note: *Dry* option, is not an option in my case.

[image]

Comment: Before someone could answer this question, they would need to know, is the top image what you started off with and is the bottom image the question being solved? If yes to both you'll need to display the bottom image as an answer so that people know that it's solved, along with the method used to get there for those that might have a similar issue. Though if its partially solved, let us know that too.

Comment: Also the blender file you provided doesn't appear to reflect the starting point of what is shown in either image. At most the file appears to be a version of your project at some step between the 1st and 2nd image. With a questionable setup and selections since for example - the timeline wasn't opened. I could name more issues with the file but that might be pedantic. However if it was a backwards or forwards compatibility issue, it would be pertinent for you in this and other occasions to announce which Blender version was used to create it. Though I would assume it was perhaps version 2.8?

Comment: As is, I hope that is helpful enough so that when you update/fix it, then others can at least help solve this, that is if it wasn't solved already.

Lastly sorry about the delayed comment update, I originally tried to put the above as an answer with a detailed reason why I couldn't put it as a comment. Yet the moderator didn't quite do their job correctly when converting answer to comment, while they basically blah blah blah'd to me about comments should be in comment section when I already stated that below 50 rep/points can't do this. So they essentially told me they didn't read it at all.